# How do I detect the temporary Internet Files location of Internet Explorer through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-extension

I am attempting to port an Firefox extension to IE. One of the features I need to have is the ability to write to the Temp Files of the browser. In Firefox this was easily done by the following code:

```
//Create file to store data transferred to desktop app
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
               getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
               get("TmpD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
    file.append("MyExtTempFile.txt");
    file.createUnique(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);
    // do whatever you need to the created file
```

This method was preferable rather than hard coding a path in because it could change on different versions of Windows / IE.

I figured out how to create and write to a file in IE by:

```
var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\MyExtTempFile.txt", true);
fh.WriteLine("Some text goes here...");
fh.Close();
```

Now I am just wondering how to automatically detect the temp file location for IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
```

Found here: [FileSystemObject.GetSpecialFolder()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/FileSystemObjectGetSpecialFolder.htm)

Answer (score 2):

`FileSystemObject.GetSpecialFolder(2)` will give you temp folder path of OS. It wont give you Temporary internet files' location.